# Is there a difference between margin values?

Tags: html, css, margin

I am working on a design and a have a div inside a div

```
<div id="header"><div id="header-top"></div></div>
```

"#header" has a dark background color and "#header-top" has a light one.  "#header also has a border-radius of 7px.

In the css "#header-top" has a margin like this "margin: 10px 0 0 10px;" so it is pushed down by 10px and to the left by 10px making it centered and the appearance of a dark border around the light inner background.

However it seems that the top 'border' is thinner than the side borders.  **Does css make it such that 10px on top is different than 10px on the sides?**

Comment: Chrome 8.0.552.215  It appears the same in FF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The top margin of #header-top is probably sticking through the edge of #header, although it is hard to say for sure out of context. See http://complexspiral.com/publications/uncollapsing-margins/

Comment: David, Thanks for the article.  However I don't know that is the problem.  It almost seems like an optical illusion, I can't seem to see wether it is or not.  The reason I asked was I thought I had seen an article that said the eye perceives certain margin situations as though they are different thicknesses.  I was wondering if anyone had heard of that before!

Comment: Take a screen shot, zoom in and count pixels if you think it is an optical illusion. There are technical reasons why it can actually happen though.

Comment: However, the border-radius suggests that the outer div has a border, in which case the margin would not collapse outside it.

Comment: David,  I took the screen shot and measured, the two are identical.  It is either my eyes, or an optical illusion of some kind.  Than being said, you all have never heard of something like what I posted right?